# Android Studio libGDX does not display errors messages when external phone is plug in

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, libgdx, runtime-error

Whenever my app throw the runtime error and using external phone plug in  (Huawei Honor 7) Ive go the error looks like this

> E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x557d1334f0

Then when I tested it on emulator Ive got normal stack trace error. In core Android develpoment everything work fine, the error are displayed correctly .

Comment: what's your Android Version ?

Comment: Android 6.0 EMUI 4.0.2

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in marshmallow and issue resolved in Android 6.0.1

Error is printed whenever switch between applications (doesn't matter which) or exit out of them, and when activities are destroyed.

You can track this issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192357)